# Novel about a dragon lord who has to wear gloves at all times

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this novel when I was young. It is probably a children's or young adult novel. I think I read it in 1997 or earlier. I remember very much enjoying it, but the title and most of the details are unfortunately quite hazy for me. Here is what I have:

- The main character was a girl in her early teens (I think)
- She was sent to live with a man who was some sort of master of dragons
- She may have been related to this man (his niece, perhaps), but I also may have made that up
- The man wore gloves at all times. When he removed them and touched someone he could see something about them. Their future, I think?

Sound familiar to anyone?

Update: Thinking back on it some more, I think I remember that the dragon lord guy and the heroine ended up in some kind of romantic relationship (making it less likely that he was her uncle). Also, he did at one point take off his gloves and touch her, seeing her future (I think).

'nother Update: It's possible that I'm confusing dragons with volcanos. Or, there may have been both. And I think they lived on an island, or a coastline?

Comment: Does [Pern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern) ring a bell? It has dragons, I don't know about the rest.

Comment: No bells there, though that series does sound like a good read!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book about a pair of siblings that had powers, the younger brother had powers to control people but concealed it the whole time?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83654/book-about-a-pair-of-siblings-that-had-powers-the-younger-brother-had-powers-to)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like the book I'm looking for too. Do any of these plot points sound familiar?
The girl has a brother (they had been recently orphaned).
She goes on a journey, and at one point frees a bunch of children and one of the kids uses a magical finding ability to find the perfect place for them all to go. 
There are rumors that the dragon lord killed his first wife, but this turns out not to be true.

I think it might be "[The Secret of Dragonhome](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590596802)" by John Peel. Is the one you were looking for?

Comment: It sure is! This has been driving me crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a somewhat jumbled recollection of the story of [Dragon's Keep](http://books.google.com/books/?id=YZEIk_-acmoC) by [Janet Lee Cary](http://www.janetleecarey.com/). Here is the synopsis from Google Books:

> Far away on Wilde Island, Princess Rosalind is born with a dragon claw where her ring finger should be. To hide this secret, the queen forces her to wear gloves at all times until a cure can be found, and Rosalind can fulfill the prophecy that will restore her family to its rightful throne. But Rosalind's flaw cannot be separated from her fate. When she is carried off by the dragon, everything she thought she knew falls apart.

[This review](http://www.yabookscentral.com/component/jreviews/discussions/review/id:13211) offers a more detailed synopsis. However, as this was only published in January 2007, it may not be the book you're looking for (how many years ago is "years ago"? :))

Comment: The book I'm thinking would've been published no later than 1997 or so. I'll update the question to reflect that, thanks!