# I thought it was called Dragon's Keep, but I can't find it

Tags: story-identification, powers, dragons

I've been trying to figure out the name of this book I once read. This is what I remember about it

- a village is attacked
- the main character and her brother escape
- they travel for sometime until they come to a Keep or an estate of some kind
- the lord of the estate lives with his daughter and a few servants
- the lord of the estate is anti social, avoids, people, and wears gloves all the time
- the estate has a history of once housing dragons
- dragons are the source of magic and those exposed to dragons gain powers
- because of their stay at the estate the main character and her brother start gaining powers
- kings have been drafting people with powers to fight their wars
- the lord of the estate hides from people because his power is that he can see a person's fate with a single touch
- the main character and the lord of the estate end up together, it happened rather awkward and quick
- the main character's brother's power is persuasion. He can get anyone to do what he wants as long as they don't know he is controlling them
- the book ends with everyone leaving the estate to hide from everyone getting drafted. The main character leaves with lord and his daughter. The brother leaves with one the estate's maid. It's hinted that the story continues in another book and the brother becomes an antagonist.

The book cover might have the main gate to the estate. The gate looks like a dragon's mouth. I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nicely detailed question; when did you read this?

Comment: I've voted to close your question as a Duplicate, but please understand that this is not a censure. This was a very good question. It's just that we have an accepted answer for it (a few, actually) and we like to link them together to improve the ability for people to find it in the future.

Comment: I personally think https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83654/book-about-a-pair-of-siblings-that-had-powers-the-younger-brother-had-powers-to?noredirect=1&lq=1 is a better answer than the current sun source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[The Secret of Dragonhome](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/764640.The_Secret_of_Dragonhome)* by John Peel might be your book.

[image: Front cover of The Secret of Dragonhome]

> Melayne and her young brother Sarrow are Talents, hunted by the King's relentless Seekers. If their Talent is discovered, they will be sent to their death. So they must hide...or die.
>
> Melayne and Sarrow find refuge at Dragonhome, the mysterious estate of the shadowy Lord Sander. Lord Sander also has something to hide--a dark and fantastical secret that haunts his every move. In order to save herself and her brother, Melayne must confront forces much stronger than her talent--tempests of magic, desire, and betrayal. If Melayne is not careful, her truth will be revealed.
>
> Melayne must unlock the secrets of Dragonhome. As danger approaches, it will be her only hope.

Found on the second page of a search for `goodreads.com dragon's keep gloves`

The Goodreads reviews mention powers stemming from dragon scales, that her brother has Persuasion powers (that he uses to betray her) and that the girl and the lord wind up together by the end of the book. Apparently, she has the ability to communicate with animals, and the lord does wear gloves at all times because he can see someone's future if he touches them.

Comment: Thank you for the accept. :) Beat me to pointing you to the [tour] to learn how to do so.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like there were two sequels, 13 and 16 years after the first book.